# How to read the coordinate values of a repeated first string in xarray?

Tags: python, python-xarray

The xarray is two dimensional (storm*time) with coordinates time, lat, and lon. I am trying to get the corresponding coordinates values of the first repeated value in xarray.

In other words, In the xarray there are nan values and repeated values of b'TD'. I want to get the time, lat, and lon values of the first b'TD' in each storm.

Here is the output of a xarray.

> <xarray.DataArray 'usa_status' (storm: 17, date_time: 36)>
> array([[nan, nan, b'TD', b'TD', b'TD', b'TD', b'TD', b'TD', b'TD', b'TD',
> b'TD', b'TD', b'TD', b'TD', b'TD', b'TD', b'TD', nan, nan, nan,
> nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
> nan, nan, nan],
> [nan, nan, b'TD', b'TD', nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
> nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
> nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
> [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, b'TD', b'TD', b'TD',
> b'TD', nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
> nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
> [b'TD', b'TD', nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
> nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
> nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
> [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, b'TD', b'TD', nan, nan,
> nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
> nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
> [b'TD', b'TD', b'TD', b'TD', b'TD', b'TD', b'TD', b'TD', b'TD',
> b'TD', b'TD', b'TD', b'TD', b'TD', nan, nan, nan, nan, b'TD',
> b'TD', b'TD', b'TD', b'TD', b'TD', b'TD', b'TD', b'TD', b'TD',
> b'TD', b'TD', b'TD', b'TD', b'TD', b'TD', b'TD', b'TD'],
> [b'TD', b'TD', nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
> nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
> nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
> [b'TD', b'TD', b'TD', b'TD', nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
> nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
> nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
> [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
> b'TD', b'TD', b'TD', b'TD', nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
> nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
> [b'TD', b'TD', b'TD', b'TD', b'TD', b'TD', b'TD', b'TD', nan, nan,
> nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
> nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
> [b'TD', b'TD', nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
> nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
> nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
> [b'TD', b'TD', b'TD', b'TD', b'TD', b'TD', b'TD', b'TD', b'TD',
> nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
> nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
> nan],
> [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, b'TD', b'TD', nan, nan, nan, nan,
> nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
> nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, b'TD', nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
> [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
> nan, nan, nan, b'TD', b'TD', nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
> nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
> [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
> nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, b'TD', b'TD', nan,
> nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
> [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
> nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, b'TD', b'TD', b'TD', b'TD', b'TD',
> b'TD', nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
> nan],
> [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
> nan, b'TD', b'TD', b'TD', b'TD', nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
> nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]],
> dtype=object)
> Coordinates:
> time     (storm, date_time) datetime64[ns] 2017-07-05T12:00:00.000039936 ... 2019-09-26T03:00:00.000039936
> lat      (storm, date_time) float32 11.8 11.880182 12.0 ... 14.5 14.634828
> lon      (storm, date_time) float32 -35.9 -36.475014 ... -37.6 -38.230053
> Dimensions without coordinates: storm, date_time
> Attributes:
> long_name:              Storm status
> description:             DB - disturbance,  TD - tropical depression,  TS...
> coverage_content_type:  thematicClassification

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to know without an example of how your data looks, however, the following may work:

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
data = np.array(
    [[np.NaN, "AB", "AB"], [np.NaN, np.NaN, "AB"], ["AB", np.NaN, np.NaN]],
    dtype=object
)
da = xr.DataArray(data)
(da == "AB").argmax(dim="dim_1")
```

`da` looks as follows:

```
<xarray.DataArray (dim_0: 3, dim_1: 3)>
array([[nan, 'AB', 'AB'],
       [nan, nan, 'AB'],
       ['AB', nan, nan]], dtype=object)
Dimensions without coordinates: dim_0, dim_1
```